# Getting error when attempting to create tests in Android while using Google APIs

Tags: android, google-api

I'm attemping to add some unit tests to my application in Intellij. Since my application uses Google Maps, I've got my Build Target set to "Google APIs (2.1)". My project compiles and runs fine, but when I attempt to create tests using either Intellij's built-in tool or the command line tool, I get this error:

> Found main project package: com.project 
>   Found main project activity: .mainActivity 
>   Error: Unable to resolve main project target 'Google Inc.\:Google APIs\:7'. You may want to install the platform in your SDK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it and it was an admittedly imperfect fix. I manually edited project.properties to change my target to android-7 and then created my test project using the command line utility. The target has since changed back to the proper target and my tests seem to be working alright now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Hi, faced the same issue: when creating junit for simple android project - the idea says the same (only for 8 api). If the command line tool fixes the issue and revert back editted project.properties - why you should had been editted them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should extend android.test.InstrumentationTestCase. Please refer to the testing tutorials for more details

(not sure what Intellij's built-in tool does though -- Is it creating Android Test Project?)

Comment: It doesn't even get to the test creation. As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html), the automated tool should be able to create a shell test, but it's at that point that I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have android SDK installed, but individual APIs come in separate packages.  Just start android tool in SDK and install missing ones.   As for testing, I would recommend to stick with normal JUnit and use mocking framework (jMockit is good choice)

Comment: I'm showing that I've got the Google API installed for Android 2.1 (my target). Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NX1sw.png).

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to the question, but FWIW, I've used [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) on GMaps projects in IntelliJ.  Works like a charm: just make sure you put the robolectric jar at the top of your module's dependencies, and mark it as a "Test" dependency so it doesn't get compiled into the app.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a gander and report back.